# I want to create language select dropdown

Tags: reactjs, redux

I want to create dynamic language select dropdown so that user can select language and when user login it reflect selected language to him.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not really geared towards "big" questions like this. How to "store" the user's language could have hundreds of options along with opinions on which to do. Try making it work, then come back with specific questions along with a minimal example of what the problem is.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: One example on how this could be solved: https://dev.to/adrai/how-to-properly-internationalize-a-react-application-using-i18next-3hdb#language-switcher

Answer (score 1):

You can use select from react material ui
[select](https://mui.com/components/selects/).
For translation you need to check this out
[i18next](https://react.i18next.com/)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).